# How can I update bios without battery in ASUS?

Tags: windows, bios, battery, asus-laptop

I want to update BIOS to new version. While the update process executes, was given an error.
The error is : the battery must be charged above 20%...

Notebook is

```
ASUS X54C with Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit)
```

And by the way the second question-yesterday the laptop run on battery, today the battery is dead

I need to update this BIOS but without the battery do not know too much how to do it

Comment: Replace the battery with a good one?

Comment: at the moment I do not have such a possibility, the battery is detected in the Windows shows loading in about 1min, next shows stop charging and battery charge 0%

Comment: Try removing the battery and just running the laptop on the charger.  Maybe the BIOS update will see you are on AC power and let you go past.

Comment: @N.Greene The Bios update normally requires battery because if you are running just on AC power and have a power cut in the middle of updating then the computer can be bricked.